# Using R into MAC OS Sierra

Tags: r, macos, rjava

I am doing a Capstone Project from Coursera Data Science using R Studio, using some packages as RWeka, rJava, RWekajars that needs Java.

I am not a specialist in Java, but I install the JRE and JDK at the same version "1.8.0_101".

When the algorithm of Tokenization was running it abort with the following message:

> Error in .jnew(name) :    java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError:
>   weka/core/tokenizers/NGramTokenizer : Unsupported major.minor version
>   51.0

I read a lot about this in others questions, but everything that I tried it doesn't work.

Let me know if someone has the same problem and if there is a solution?

Thanks. 
(My hardware is a MAC i5 with 8GB and 1TB HD. My software is a macOS Sierra 10.12).

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if this is the root cause of the issue, but I did have to do these steps to get rJava and RWeka installed.

These commands needed to install rJava and remaining libraries properly

```
sudo ln -s $(/usr/libexec/java_home)/jre/lib/server/libjvm.dylib /usr/local/lib

sudo R CMD javareconf

LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)/jre/lib/server: open -a RStudio

install.packages("rJava",type='source')

install.packages("RWeka",type='source')

install.packages(c("NLP", "openNLP", "qdap"))
```